# Unable to parse inventory script as an inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

My python script dynamically queries and generates a JSON file as follows:

```
{
    "all": {
      "hosts": [
        "192.158.1.1"
      ], 
      "vars": {
        "ansible_become_method": "sudo", 
        "ansible_become": "yes"
      }
    }
  }
```

But somehow when I execute the command below

```
ansible -i script.py -m ping
```

it gives out the following warning messages

- [WARNING] Unable to parse /etc/ansible/script.py as an inventory source
- [WARNING] No inventory was parse, only implicit localhost is available.
- [WARNING] provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

I don't know what I'm missing or wrong as I'm new to dynamic inventory with Ansible.

When I run `ansible-inventory -i script.py --list` I got the following response

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    }, 
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }, 
    "ungrouped": {}
}
```

My Ansible version is 2.7.7

Inventory plugin is script

```
enable_plugins = script
```

**[Updated]** Running -v based on Steve's suggestion gives me a bit more

```
 [WARNING]:  * Failed to parse /etc/ansible/newhost.py with script plugin: failed to parse executable inventory script results from /etc/ansible/script.py: Syntax
Error while loading YAML.   mapping values are not allowed in this context  The error appears to have been in '<string>': line 3, column 8, but may be elsewhere in the
file depending on the exact syntax problem.


 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/plugins/inventory/script.py", line 125, in parse
    raise AnsibleError("failed to parse executable inventory script results from {0}: {1}\n{2}".format(path, to_native(e), err))
```

Comment: Run `ansible-inventory -i script.py --list -vvv`, it will tell you which plugin Ansible is using and provide additional information about the decisions it makes. It should be using the `script` plugin.

Comment: Thanks @SteveE.for the hint. I updated the question with more output. I thought I would be fine with returned JSON format which Ansible would be able to parse

Comment: `enable_plugins = script` can't be what your Ansible is using. The output clearly shows the `host_list`, `yaml` and other plugins are being tried. However it doesn't list the `script` plugin which is unexpected. [The defaults are here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory.html)

Comment: @SteveE.updated the output. Seems to be related to cache which I doubt.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added a header like this in the very first line of your python inventory script?

```
#!/path/to/python
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script needs to be executable:

```
$ chmod a+x script.py
```

See docs about using scripts [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#inventory-script-example-cobbler).

Your script must also [accept certain arguments](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory-scripts).

Comment: Setting chmod doesn't make it work. Yes my script also has --list as argument and when I run it with --list it returns a JSON format.

Comment: Provide the full path maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the command like this

```sh
ansible-inventory -i 'path-to-the-file/script.py' --list
```

Is important to have the quotation marks. On OsX for me this was the problem.